# How to extrapolate data from an nmap scan result

Tags: python-2.7, nmap

I'm still quite new to Python and I'm currently looking at network scanning for available hosts. With my current code, I can search an IP range to determine if hosts are available or not. However, how can I restrict what information the nmap scan results show me, or is there a function I need to be using to only show the host IP address, scan time and if its available?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import nmap
import sys

nm = nmap.PortScannerAsync()


def callback_result(host, scan_result):
    print '------------------'
    print host, scan_result


try:
    nm.scan('192.168.1.86-87', arguments='-O -v', callback=callback_result)
    while nm.still_scanning():
        print('<<< Scanning >>>')
        nm.wait(2)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print 'Cancelling current operation'
    sys.exit()

except KeyError as e:
    pass
```

This provides the output which is broad and contains too much information;

```
192.168.1.87 {'nmap': {'scanstats': {'uphosts': u'0', 'timestr': u'Wed Apr  8 13:28:29 2015', 'downhosts': u'1', 'totalhosts': u'1', 'elapsed': u'3.77'},
 'scaninfo': {u'tcp': {'services': u'1,3-4,6-7,9,13,17,19-26,30,32-33,37,42-43,49,53,70,79-85,88-90,99-100,106,109-111,113,119,125,135,139,143-
144,146,161,163,179,199,211-212,222,254-
256,259,264,280,301,306,311,340,366,389,406-407,416-417,425,427,443-445,458,464-
465,481,497,500,512-515,524,541,543-545,548,554-555,563,587,593,616-617,625,631,636,646,648,666-
668,683,687,691,700,705,711,714,720,722,726,749,765,777,783,787,800-
801,808,843,873,880,888,898,900-903,911-912,981,987,990,992-993,995,999-
1002,1007,1009-1011,1021-1100,1102,1104-1108,1110-1114,1117,1119,1121-
1124,1126,1130-1132,1137-1138,1141,1145,1147-1149,1151-1152,1154,1163-
1166,1169,1174-1175,1183,1185-1187,1192,1198-1199,1201,1213,1216-1218,1233-1234,1236,1244,1247-1248,1259,1271-1272,1277,1287,1296,1300-1301,1309-1311,1322,1328,1334,1352,1417,1433-1434,1443,1455,1461,1494,1500-1501,1503,1521,1524,1533,1556,1580,1583,1594,1600,1641,1658,1666,1687-1688,1700,1717-1721,1723,1755,1761,1782-1783,1801,1805,1812,1839-1840,1862-1864,1875,1900,1914,1935,1947,1971-1972,1974,1984,1998-2010,2013,2020-2022,2030,2033-2035,2038,2040-2043,2045-2049,2065,2068,2099-2100,2103,2105-2107,2111,2119,2121,2126,2135,2144,2160-2161,2170,2179,2190-2191,2196,2200,2222,2251,2260,2288,2301,2323,2366,2381-2383,2393-2394,2399,2401,2492,2500,2522,2525,2557,2601-2602,2604-2605,2607-2608,2638,2701-2702,2710,2717-2718,2725,2800,2809,2811,2869,2875,2909-2910,2920,2967-2968,2998,3000-3001,3003,3005-3007,3011,3013,3017,3030-3031,3052,3071,3077,3128,3168,3211,3221,3260-3261,3268-3269,3283,3300-3301,3306,3322-3325,3333,3351,3367,3369-3372,3389-3390,3404,3476,3493,3517,3527,3546,3551,3580,3659,3689-3690,3703,3737,3766,3784,3800-3801,3809,3814,3826-3828,3851,3869,3871,3878,3880,3889,3905,3914,3918,3920,3945,3971,3986,3995,3998,4000-4006,4045,4111,4125-4126,4129,4224,4242,4279,4321,4343,4443-4446,4449,4550,4567,4662,4848,4899-4900,4998,5000-5004,5009,5030,5033,5050-5051,5054,5060-5061,5080,5087,5100-5102,5120,5190,5200,5214,5221-5222,5225-5226,5269,5280,5298,5357,5405,5414,5431-5432,5440,5500,5510,5544,5550,5555,5560,5566,5631,5633,5666,5678-5679,5718,5730,5800-5802,5810-5811,5815,5822,5825,5850,5859,5862,5877,5900-5904,5906-5907,5910-5911,5915,5922,5925,5950,5952,5959-5963,5987-5989,5998-6007,6009,6025,6059,6100-6101,6106,6112,6123,6129,6156,6346,6389,6502,6510,6543,6547,6565-6567,6580,6646,6666-6669,6689,6692,6699,6779,6788-6789,6792,6839,6881,6901,6969,7000-7002,7004,7007,7019,7025,7070,7100,7103,7106,7200-7201,7402,7435,7443,7496,7512,7625,7627,7676,7741,7777-7778,7800,7911,7920-7921,7937-7938,7999-8002,8007-8011,8021-8022,8031,8042,8045,8080-8090,8093,8099-8100,8180-8181,8192-8194,8200,8222,8254,8290-8292,8300,8333,8383,8400,8402,8443,8500,8600,8649,8651-8652,8654,8701,8800,8873,8888,8899,8994,9000-9003,9009-9011,9040,9050,9071,9080-9081,9090-9091,9099-9103,9110-9111,9200,9207,9220,9290,9415,9418,9485,9500,9502-9503,9535,9575,9593-9595,9618,9666,9876-9878,9898,9900,9917,9929,9943-9944,9968,9998-10004,10009-10010,10012,10024-10025,10082,10180,10215,10243,10566,10616-10617,10621,10626,10628-10629,10778,11110-11111,11967,12000,12174,12265,12345,13456,13722, 13782-
13783,14000,14238,14441-14442,15000,15002-15004,15660,15742,16000-
16001,16012,16016,16018,16080,16113,16992-16993,17877,17988,18040,18101,18988,19101,19283,19315,19350,19780,19801,19842,20
000,20005,20031,20221-20222,20828,21571,22939,23502,24444,24800,25734-
25735,26214,27000,27352-27353,27355-
27356,27715,28201,30000,30718,30951,31038,31337,32768-32785,33354,33899,34571-
34573,35500,38292,40193,40911,41511,42510,44176,44442-
44443,44501,45100,48080,49152-49161,49163,49165,49167,49175-49176,49400,49999-50003,50006,50300,50389,50500,50636,50800,51103,51493,52673,52822,52848,52869,54
045,54328,55055-55056,55555,55600,56737-
56738,57294,57797,58080,60020,60443,61532,61900,62078,63331,64623,64680,65000,65
129,65389', 'method': u'syn'}}, 'command_line': u'nmap -oX - -O -v 
192.168.1.87'}, 'scan': {u'192.168.1.87': {'status': {'state': u'down', 
'reason': u'no-response'}, 'hostname': '', 'vendor': {}, 'addresses': {u'ipv4': 
u'192.168.1.87'}}}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can address this from two directions: what actions Nmap takes, and what you do with the output.

The Nmap options in your program (`-O -v`) instruct Nmap to do the following things:

- Increase verbosity (`-v`). This doesn't matter for `python-nmap` because it uses the XML output, which doesn't change based on verbosity.
- Check if the host is up (default).
- Check for a reverse-DNS name for the host (default).
- Scan the top 1000 TCP ports on the host (default).
- Fingerprint the host's OS based on TCP/IP stack quirks (`-O`).

If all you want is whether the host is up, you should leave off the `-O` and use some other options to turn off the other parts of Nmap's default behavior:

- `-n` will turn off reverse-DNS name resolution.
- `-sn` will turn off the port scan.

The scan information like time will always be printed.

Secondly, your callback function currently just prints the string representation of the scan object. If you want less output, then use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) to select the object attributes that you want to print.

Comment: Hi there, I've attempted to use the String format for Accessing arguments by position: print {},{}.format(scan_result)

But it gives me an error:
    AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'
So obviously I'm doing it wrong... Any ideas on how to get that bit working?

Comment: @LukeWillmer You'll have to traverse the `scan_result` with Python code and print out the parts you want. Something like `print "{0}: {1}".format(host, scan_result["scan"][host]["status"]["state"])`

Comment: I've implemented your code, which gives me this: http://pastebin.com/bvJWr3N6

But there isn't an output;

root@kali:~/Desktop/myScripts# python networkScan.py
root@kali:~/Desktop/myScripts#

Comment: @LukeWillmer Spend some time with some basic Python tutorials first. You are missing a lot of basics of the language; your script defines one function and does not run anything.